# Django ckeditor

Tags: django, ckeditor

I'm going to use ckeditor in my django platform.

My settings is:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ".."))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'static/media')
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, 'uploads')
CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'
CKEDITOR_MEDIA_PREFIX  = "/media/ckeditor/"
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PREFIX = "http://fortezzeimperiali/media/uploads/"
CKEDITOR_RESTRICT_BY_USER = True
CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = "pillow"
```

But when I browse my image I get this error:

```
fortezzeimperiali/static/media/uploads/sega/2015/03/21/schermata-2014-11-30-alle-003712.png HTTP/1.1" 404 2857
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a setup which always works for me, perhaps you can try:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'static'

# CKEditor settings
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"
CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'
#This ensures you have all toolbar icons
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': None, 
        },
    }
```

And of course, you should have ckeditor in your INSTALLED APPS

```
....
'ckeditor',
...
```

And add ckeditor to your urls:

```
(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor.urls')),
```

I'm sure you've seen this page: https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor

Comment: You saved me a lot of time.

Comment: @Iman I believe the setup still works for 1.10 django. Glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use an valid domain, not fortezzeimperiali alone?

KEDITOR_UPLOAD_PREFIX = "http://fortezzeimperiali**.com**/media/uploads/"

Answer (score 0):

If everything is working okay, but the image isn't being grabbed, maybe you forgot to run `python manage.py collectstatic` after installing?

Or, if it's just an issue of not seeing the thumbnails in the image browser (but you're getting the preview when you click on the broken-thumbnail images), then you just need to run `python manage.py generateckeditorthumbnails` to generate thumbnails for the images already on your server. Those not being there will causes you to see some 404's come over the network, but won't cause the site to break or anything. But running that command would make them go away, if that's the case.